# Array.prototype.slice.call Does not work in IE

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE only javascript error with getElementsByTagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143848/ie-only-javascript-error-with-getelementsbytagname)

```
var rows=myTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');   
rows=Array.prototype.slice.call(rows,0);
```

Does not work in IE, is there any other way, to convert this into a real array, so that I could use a sort function over it...?

Comment: That is weird, it should work just fine AFAIK.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE, works nicely in other browsers, damn with IE...

Comment: Add an `alert(typeof rows)` to help narrow down the problem.  If `rows === null` then your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a loop if IE version < 8.

```
var rows=myTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');   
var row_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  row_array.push(rows[i]);
}
```