# how to change '(1,2,3,4)' to '1,2,3,4'

Tags: javascript, string

this is my code:

```
    var a='(1,2,3,4)'
    a=a.slice(-1,1)
    alert(a)
```

and i print nothing.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
a = a.slice(1, -1);
```

Comment: And please see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120804/difference-between-array-slice-and-array-slice

Answer (score 2):

```
a.substring(1,a.length-1)
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 2):

What about :

```
'(1,2,3,4)'.replace(/[()]/g, '')
```

Which will remove all ( and ) characters in the string, giving you :

```
"1,2,3,4"
```

Comment: @Pascal: don't you think a regex is a bit overkill for this sort of thing?  For a more complex operation, regexes are fine, I just wonder about whether it's a good idea to encourage regexes where they are not needed.

Comment: It might ^^ *(I'm one of those who says not to use regex too often -- should have said it in my answer)* ; but it was a possible solution that no-one proposed ; so I thought it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
var a='(1,2,3,4)';
a.replace(/^\((.*)\)$/, "$1");
```